# SQL crash on database file rewrite android

Tags: android, mysql, android-database

I am trying to backup the database files generated in my app to a `.zip` file and then extract them to restore to `/data/data/<packagename>/databases/` folder. I am zipping only the database files and not `-journal files`. When i click on the restore option the `.db` files are unzipped and moved to the `/databases/` folder. The problem here is i am having crash while moving the files. Below is the error log:

```
E/UncaughtException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032)
                                                                          #################################################################
                                                                          Error Code : 1032 (SQLITE_READONLY_DBMOVED)
                                                                          Caused By : Database or Journal file have been removed.
                                                                            (attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032))
                                                                          #################################################################
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
```

Function to move files after unzipping:

```
public void moveContents(){
        File destinationFolder = new File(DATABASE_FOLDER_PATH);
        File sourceFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AppName/Backups/_extracts");
        if (!destinationFolder.exists())
        {
            destinationFolder.mkdirs();
        }
        // Check weather source exists and it is folder.
        if (sourceFolder.exists() && sourceFolder.isDirectory())
        {
            // Get list of the files and iterate over them
            File[] listOfFiles = sourceFolder.listFiles();
            if (listOfFiles != null)
            {
                for (File child : listOfFiles )
                {
                    try {
                        File checkFile=new File(destinationFolder+"/"+child.getName());
                        if(checkFile.exists()){
                            checkFile.delete();
                            FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(child,destinationFolder,false);
                        }else{
                            FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(child,destinationFolder,false);
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("FLERROR","ERROR",e);
                    }
                    // Move files to destination folder
                }

                // Add if you want to delete the source folder
                sourceFolder.delete();
            }
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println(sourceFolder + "  Folder does not exists");
        }
    }
```

The application is crashing and is closed.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your Error log , It seems like you are trying to move database which is only readonly . You are gonna have to take writable permission for your database .

So before moving your database . make it writable using this .

```
String yourpath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
SQLiteDatabase yourdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(yourpath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```